# Using Webclient to POST/select all the option Values of a Multiselect

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to write an application to automate router configuration. Unfortunately with the router we are using, telnet is not an option.

So I have had to interface with the Cisco web interface using C# WebClient class.

Up until now I had been able to set everything I needed using NameValueCollection and WebClient.UploadValues.

I would take all the input elements on the form, then just upload the name value Collection corresponding to the input types on the form, setting the values of each to the desired setting.

But now I have run into a problem.

With one of the forms, it is using a multiselect control to handle an array of input data, not an input type.

I am at a total loss for how to set this.

The html for the multiselect is as follows

```
<select multiple class="MultiSelect" name="PortRangeList" size="12" onChange="showList(this.form.PortRangeList);" style="width: 100%">
    <option value="All Traffic{[(*-*-*)]}1;0;1;65535;0}">All Traffic [TCP&UDP/1~65535]</option>
    <option value="DNS{[(*-*-*)]}2;17;53;53;0}">DNS [UDP/53~53]</option>
    <option value="FTP{[(*-*-*)]}3;6;21;21;0}">FTP [TCP/21~21]</option>
    ...
</select>
```

When I was using the input types, I would simply do the following

```
NameValueCollection formNetworkData = new NameValueCollection();
formNetworkData["ipAddr"] = "192.168.1.2";
formNetworkData["lanMask"] = "255.255.255.0";
downloadedData = _routerWebClient.UploadValues(_routerIP + NETWORK, formNetworkData);
```

But looking at the code for this new form, it appears right before it submits, it selects all the options in the multiselect.

I realize I have probably asked this question poorely, but any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

---

Using Chrome debugger PortRangeList is exactly as you said.

There are 5 input types

submitStatus, upnpOpen (etc...)

For those my code looks like this

```
NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
formData["submitStatus"]="1";
formData["upnpOpen"]="0";
downloadedData = _routerWebClient.UploadValues(SERVICE0, formData);
```

But in order to submit the PortRangeList data, I can't use the NameValueCollection because it does not allow a name to have muliple values.

how could submit that?

WebClient.UploadData, WebClient.UploadFile or WebClient.UploadString maybe?

Comment: [You don't need tags in your titles.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/102937)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to compare what goes over the wire when it works ("normal" browser) and when it doesn't work (your code)... once you know the differences you can change your code accordingly...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In the end I found Chrome had the ability built in to view the form data being posted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in the selected options by passing in the "PortRangeList" parameter multiple times, once for each option:

```
PortRangeList=All Traffic{[(*-*-*)]}1;0;1;65535;0}&PortRangeList=DNS{[(*-*-*)]}2;17;53;53;0}&PortRangeList=FTP{[(*-*-*)]}3;6;21;21;0}
```

That's how browsers do it. Since you're using the WebClient, try this:

```
PortRangeList=All Traffic{[(*-*-*)]}1;0;1;65535;0},DNS{[(*-*-*)]}2;17;53;53;0},FTP{[(*-*-*)]}3;6;21;21;0}
```

Obviously, everything has to be properly URL-escaped.

Comment: Using Chrome debugger PortRangeList is exactly as you said.

There are 5 input types

submitStatus, upnpOpen (etc...)

For those my code looks like this

NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
formData["submitStatus"]="1";
formData["upnpOpen"]="0";
downloadedData = _routerWebClient.UploadValues(SERVICE0, formData);

But in order to submit the PortRangeList data, I can't use the NameValueCollection because it does not allow a name to have muliple values.

how could submit that?

WebClient.UploadData, WebClient.UploadFile or WebClient.UploadString maybe?

Comment: Read my answer again, especially the 2nd code block - just join the values with "," (commas) and pass in as a single value, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would post the final answer.

In the end I used the exact solution shown here.
http://anhonga.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/using-webclient-with-uploadvalues-and-uploadstring-to-simulate-post/

This is with his code, but I did essentially the exact same thing (without using global variables)

```
StringBuilder _strBld = new StringBuilder();
int _intItemCount = 0;

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Net.WebClient myWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
    myWebClient.Headers.Add("Charset", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); // ◄  This line is essential

// Perform server-side validations (same as before)
if (this.F_Name.Text.Length == 0 || this.L_Name.Text.Length == 0)
{ AppendError("First and Last name must be provided"); }
…

// Add the user-provided name values
AppendUploadString("last_name", this.L_Name.Text);
AppendUploadString ("first_name", this.F_Name.Text);
AppendUploadString ("address", this.Address.Text);

// Add the Toppings
foreach (ListItem item in this.ToppingsChkBoxList.Items)
{
if (item.Selected)
    {
        AppendUploadString("Toppings", item.Value.ToString());
    }
}

myWebClient.UploadString("https http://www.Destination.com/...?encoding=UTF-8", "POST", _strBld.ToString());
}

private void AppendUploadString(string strName, string strValue)

{
    _intItemCount++;
    _strBld.Append((intItemCount == 1 ? "" : "&") + strName + "=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strValue));
    // Update: Use UrlEncode to ensure that the special characters are included in the submission
}
```